# Win32: why does my PRINTDLG (or PRINTDLGEX) have gray background?

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

I'm creating an Win32 application with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 RC. I'm using C++.

When I call `PrintDlg()` or `PrintDlgEx()`, the resulting dialog has gray background. Anyway, the same dialog in all other programs I have checked has white background.

I see that there are ways of handling `WM_CTLCOLORDLG` to set the background color of a dialog, but since all other applications have the same behavior, I don't think they all were built to handle this message in the same way.

I include here the code I use to open the dialog with `PrintDlg()`:

```
PRINTDLG print_dialog{
    sizeof(PRINTDLG),
    hWnd,
    NULL, NULL, NULL,
    0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    1,
    NULL, 0,
    NULL,
};
if (PrintDlg(&print_dialog))
{
    ...
}
```

And the code for `PrintDlgEx()`:

```
PRINTDLGEX print_dialog = {};
print_dialog.lStructSize = sizeof(PRINTDLGEX);
print_dialog.hwndOwner = hWnd;
print_dialog.Flags = PD_NOPAGENUMS;
print_dialog.nStartPage = START_PAGE_GENERAL;
if (PrintDlgEx(&print_dialog))
{
    ...
}
```

What is wrong in my application?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use PrintDlgEx() instead.

Comment: @HansPassant I've already tried using `PrintDlgEx()`, but I obtain the same result.

Comment: Please show the code where you're using [PrintDlgEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646942.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable I've included the code using PrintDlgEx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely your process is not themed because it has not manifested v6 comctl32. Non-themed dialogs default to a button face colored background. Themed dialogs have a white background.

Add the comctl32 v6 manifest to your executable.